# How do I check the current contents of a file in Gradle

Tags: file, gradle, order-of-execution

First and formost... I'm new to Gradle.  Having said that, I *love* it.  Unfortunatly, I've hit a snag.  I have a series of tasks that are part of a deploy process.  One (`buildProject`) Calls a shell script, that as part of it's process updates a `REVISION` file with the new "version".  After that the `deployToRemote` task is called to deploy the latest version to the server. It calls `getCurrentVersion` to read the latest version from the `REVISION` file. All of these tasks are outlined below.  The problem is that it appears that `getLatestVersion` is called *first* in spite of proper `mustRunAfter` statements, as it always reads in the "PRE" `buildProject` version listed in the `REVISION` file.  How can I make sure that `getLatestVersion` reads the file ***after*** `buildProject` runs?

Here are the tasks:

buildProject:

```
task buildProject(type:Exec) {
  def command = ['./make-release', '-f']
  if (deployEnvironment != 'stage') {
    command = ['./make-release', "-e ${deployEnvironment}"]
  }

  commandLine command
}
```

deployToRemote

```
task deployToRemote(dependsOn: 'getCurrentVersion') {
  doLast {
    def version = tasks.getCurrentVersion.hash()
    println "Using version ${version}"
    println "Using user ${webhostUser}"
    println "Using host ${webhostUrl}"
    ssh.run {
      session(remotes.webhost) {
        put from: "dist/project-${version}.tar.gz", into: '/srv/staging/'
        execute "cd /srv/staging; ./manual_install.sh ${version}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

getCurrentVersion

```
task getCurrentVersion {
  def line
  new File("REVISION").withReader { line = it.readLine() }
  ext.hash = {
    line
  }
}
```

My `build.gradle` file has this at the end:

```
deployToRemote.mustRunAfter buildProject
getCurrentVersion.mustRunAfter buildProject
```

The `REVISION` file looks like this;

```
1196.dev10
919b642fd5ca5037a437dac28e2cfac0ea18ceed
dev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle build has [three phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html): Initialization, Configuration and Execution.

The problem you faced is that code in `getCurrentVersion` is executed in the configuration phase. In the configuration phase the code in tasks is executed in the order of their definition and dependencies are not taken into account.

Consider this example:

```
task second(dependsOn: 'first') {
    println 'second: this is executed during the configuration phase.'
    doLast {
      println 'second: This is executed during the execution phase.'
    }
}

task first {
    println 'first: this is executed during the configuration phase.'
    doLast {
      println 'first: This is executed during the execution phase.'
    }
}

second.mustRunAfter first
```

If you execute `gradle -q second` you'll get:

```
second: this is executed during the configuration phase.
first: this is executed during the configuration phase.
first: This is executed during the execution phase.
second: This is executed during the execution phase.
```

To fix your script you need to put the code into `doLast` like this:

```
task getCurrentVersion {
  doLast {
     def line
     new File("REVISION").withReader { line = it.readLine() }
     ext.hash = {
       line
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course! So obvious, so simple and SO perfect.  Thanks @roman-konaval!